# How to use location.hash to open bootstrap panel/tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to link to a specific panel of a bootstrap 3 accordion. The links will be in a navigation menu, so sometimes the links will be on the same page as the accordion, and sometimes they will be on a different page. I have an example that works when the links are on a different page, but it doesn't work if you're on the same page. I need it to work in both cases.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 // open panel when linked from an external link (this works)
       location.hash && $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');  

 // open panel when link is on the same page (incorrectly requires double click) 
        $(".nav-left a").on("click", function() {
            location.hash && $(location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
        });

});
```

Here is a demo that shows it opening the correct panel from an external link:

http://www.bootply.com/render/123550/#service2

(You may need to copy and paste this URL into your browser if it doesn't work.)

But if you try to use the links once you're already on the page, you have to double click them to get them to open the corresponding panel.

Here's the link to the full bootply with my code: http://www.bootply.com/123550

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You might want to use the window's `hashchange` event to decide which part of the accordion to expand. There are also jQuery plugins for that, e.g. [this one](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) and [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/hashchange/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` handler for a link is executed **before** the browser follows the link, so your handler function will still see the old `location.hash`.

To circumvent that, you can either

- react to the window's `hashchange` event (which has the advantage that it will even work when the user uses the forward/back buttons) *or*
- determine the section to be opened from the link's hash instead of the location's hash.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can use the link's hash to open the section? I tried a few variations that did not work. $('.nav-left a[href="#' + '.collapse' + '"]').collapse('show'); and $(this.hash).collapse('show'); for example.

Comment: @Lindsay Just replace `location.hash` with `this.hash` in your click handler in the "open panel when linked from same page" section. Since the handler is bound to all matching `<a>` tags, `this` will refer to the link that was clicked. However, as I said, you would do your users a favour by using `window.onhashchange` (possibly in addition to the click handler) to handle the forward/back buttons properly.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Don't know why I tried to overcomplicate it!